# Backbone Collection View each

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, collections, each

I'm new to Backbone.js and getting some trouble with collection view.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var customersCollection = new _App.Collections.Customers();
var customersView = new _App.Views.Customers({collection: customersCollection});
customersView.render();
```

And here's a view - I can't understand why I cannot iterate over collection:

```
_App.Views.Customers = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        console.log('Here is my collection');
        console.log(this.collection);
        console.log('Now lets iterate over it...');
        _.each(this.collection, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
        }, this);
        console.log('...done');
        return this;
    }
});
```

What I see in chrome console:

```
Here is my collection
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "/admin/customers/latest.json"…}
    _byId: Object
    length: 5
    models: Array[5]
    __proto__: Surrogate
Now lets iterate over it...
...done
```

So I can't figure out why I can see a collection but can't each over it.
Thanks

**// SOLVED**

I have found why this was going to happen.
Completely missed that .fetch() is asynchronous, so when render() was called, data were still not present in collection.
This code works for me now, so I can go on with templates, etc

```
_App.Views.Customers = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new _App.Collections.Customers();
        this.collection.on('sync', this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
        return this;
    }
});

new _App.Views.Customers();
```

Regards, Nikolay

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `_.each` appropriately.

Should be:

```
 _.each(this.collection.models, function(item) {
   console.log(item);
 },this);
```

or better yet:

```
 this.collection.each(function(item) {
   console.log(item);
 });
```

Comment: Trying this.collection.each(function(item) { console.log(item); }); but result is exactly same - noting is going to be in console.log() inside iteration function

Comment: Are there any models in your collection?